# Calculated covariance & corr. coefficient - confirmation

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have 2 simple discrete random variables.

```
Marginal distribution of X:
V:    0.002    0.004    0.006    0.008 
P:    0.110    0.480    0.300    0.110 

Marginal distribution of Y:
V:    0.010    0.020    0.030    0.040 
P:    0.100    0.400    0.300    0.200
```

Here 
V means values
P means their respective probabilities

I calculated these below but I am not sure about the last 2:

```
E[X] = 0.00482000 
E[Y] = 0.02600000 
var[X] = 0.000002727600 
var[Y] = 0.000084000000 

covariance (X,Y) = -0.000001120000 
correlation coefficient (X,Y) = -0.073992557516
```

1) Could someone confirm these 6 calculated numbers please?

2) What are the best free tools to calculate such things? Maybe R, Python? 
(Please don't downvote for the 2nd question, I will remove it if needed).
I looked at a few online calculators but none of them seems to take   probabilities as input, just 2 vectors of values they take.

Comment: Someone's going to downvote for the first! Try to write out how you arrived to these values: here is more likely that someone will comment your thought process than your results.

Comment: @N74 I just applied the formulas. I wrote a program in Java and those are the values it produced. But some of them do not match with the answers given in my book.

Comment: My suggestion is to copy the formulas, so that we can see if they are the expected ones and if they were correctly applied to your data.

Comment: @N74 What is this?! These are basic well-known formulas. If you don't intend to help what is your goal in posting these comments?!

Comment: I want to help whoever will come and find this question in the future because he found it using the search features. A question like this, at the moment, will only help you now, so it is out of the scope of this site.

Comment: The means and variances look correct. You do not seem to have information about the relationship between $X$ and $Y$, so it is difficult to see how you calculated their covariance and correlation - if they were independent then both would be zero

Comment: @Henry Thanks. They are not independent. Their joint distribution was given and from it I calculated the marginal distributions (in the usual way). And yes I am pretty confident that the first 4 values are correct, but I am not fully sure about the last two.

Comment: @N74 Well it might be useful to someone else too. It's just a problem/exercise with answers (my answers) given. I just wanted these answers to be confirmed by somebody more knowledgeable. If problems (clearly stated) are off topic then I am not sure what is, sorry.

Comment: I realized that I should have provided the join distribution of X and Y.